# data.frame in R from text

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a text (from a text file with one line), something like `hello world`.

I want to convert this text in a data.frame that looks like this.

```
  V1 V2
1  h 0
1  e 1
1  l 0
1  l 0
1  o 1
1  <SPACE>  NA
1  w 0
1  o 1
1  r 0
1  l 0
1  d 0
```

All vals should have value 1, all other letters value 0 and all  should be NA.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strsplit` to split your character string and `grepl` to find the vowels:

```
mystring <- "hello world"
df <- data.frame(V1 = unlist(strsplit(mystring, "")))
df$V2 <- as.numeric(grepl("[aeiou]", df$V1))

>df
#   V1 V2
#1   h  0
#2   e  1
#3   l  0
#4   l  0
#5   o  1
#6      0
#7   w  0
#8   o  1
#9   r  0
#10  l  0
#11  d  0
```

If you want to replace `0` by `NA` for empty cells in `V1`, you could use `ifelse`:

```
df$V2 <- ifelse(df$V1 == " ", NA, df$V2)
```